# Book in which curses are invisible, whereas "gifts" are overt

Tags: story-identification

I read a book some time ago in which one of the plot twists was that a person was cursed - not as a punishment as is traditional, but as a way to grant power without drawing the kind of attention a positive divine investiture would do.

If I remember rightly, there's a line in the explanation to the tune of "a blessing rings out and shines to all, whereas a curse, is dark, quiet, and most importantly, secret".

Does this ring any bells with anyone? Its a clever take on the trope, so I'd like to find and re-read it to see how the rest of the story holds up, as I can remember nothing else about it.

Comment: It´s not exactly what you are looking for, but it sounds a little bit like "The Curse of Chalion" from Lois McMaster.

Comment: @Julian That's not the book I was thinking of, but it looks like something I might want to look into regardless - thanks!

Comment: Sounds really interesting, I hope you get an answer..

Do you remember anything else? When you read it, rough publishing date/how longyou had it, book cover?

Comment: @Stormie: Unfortunately that is everything I remember about it, everything else is a blank. I read it maybe 5 - 15 years ago, which I doubt is a specific enough timeframe to be terribly helpful, and no recollection of the rest of the plot, or anything about the cover art etc

Comment: Even if it's broad, you should enter that timeframe into the question and title. You never know what will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it may be possible that you may be referring to the Tamuli Series by David Eddings. Domes of Fire, The Shining Ones and The Hidden City. One of the races in the books - 'The Shining Ones' are feared as they can cause death with a touch and have other abilities given to them by their God. The gift took the form of a curse to conceal and protect them. This is described in one of the books as "A blessing rings and shimmers in the lucid air like bell-sound, but a curse is dark and silent".

Comment: Ah, that is exactly it, thank you! That's one of my favourite series', I don't know why I didn't realise that that's where it was from, but thank you for helping me join the dots